# How to export a file through Programs?

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-export

In the UI for Programs, I was unable to create a step of transferring the file.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to make sure the File Transfer Activity (under Interactions in the UI) is setup before you create your program. By default this will use the Enhanced FTP account setup with your Marketing Cloud account.

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/file_transfer_activity/

To add a custom File Transfer location (i.e. your corporate FTP) see here:
http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/file_transfer_location/

Comment: Thanks Rob. Would you mind updating your answer to copy and paste the gist of the links, in case they change in the future?